# woocommerce returns old thumbnail size after changing media settings

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce

I need to change woocommerce thumbnail size from 180x180 to 173x173. I have set in the functions.php the proper code and regenerated thumbnails with Regenerate Thumbnails plugin. All good so far.
The problem is that some of the products take the new size (173x173) properly and some retain the old size 180x180. 
I want to delete the old thumbs but i don't get why some of the products are still reading that dimension.

Thank you

Comment: check your files, to see if you have both sizes - also, clear your cache, and instead of overwriting the thumbnail size, did you create a new one? like `woocommerce_custom_thumb_size` - and lastly, if nothing else works, create a CSS rule that targets your thumbclass - something like `img.woocommerce-thumb-class` or similar, and set it as a max width `img.woocommerce-thumb-class {max-width:173px;}` or on the container

Comment: If you have both sizes and the name is the same, wordpress can get confused

Comment: Fixed. Turned out that the images that have less than 173 in height does not display. So i changed the resize value to 0x173 and worked well.

Comment: Thank your for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Turned out that the images that have less than 173 in height does not display. So i changed the resize value to 0x173 and worked well.